# Text indent starting from 2nd paragraph

Tags: html, css, text-indent

I have text from DB ($row[text] ), it looks like:

```html
<p>First</p>
<p>Second</p>
<p>Third</p>
```

And i want to apply  "text-indent" starting from the 2nd paragraph.
I know, that it can be applied with class like:

```css
.a{text-indent: 20px}
```

```html
<p>First</p>
<p class="a">Second</p>
<p class="a">Third</p>
```

But i can't do that cuz i cant edit database.
And when i use 
p{text-indent: 20px}
it applies to all paragraphs

Comment: `p:nth-child(2) { ... }` but not 100% sure. You want starting from 2nd and the rest after?

Comment: What @Fred-ii- said might work, or you could try: `p {text-indent:20px;} p:nth-child(1) {text-indent: 0;}` which should indent all paragraphs but the first one.

Comment: @Tom Yours looks more promising. I'm a tad out of touch with CSS. I've been too busy concentrating on SQL lol

Comment: `p:nth-child(1+n) { ... }` is what you are looking for

Comment: @Tom Seems like someone picked up on your suggestion.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's fine. As long as Little Fox got the answer s/he needed.

Comment: @Tom I agree. Let's call it an "assist" ;-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by applying the `text-indent` to all `p` tags, and removing it on the `first-child`:

```css
p{text-indent: 20px}
p:first-child{text-indent:0}
```

```html
<p>First</p>
<p>Second</p>
<p>Third</p>
```

Comment: This means that e.g. a `p` element immediately following a heading will be indented (as it is not a first child of its parent), contrary to typographic practices.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the markup context of the `p` elements and on the desired typographic practices. For example, should a `p` element be indented if it follows a list, or a table? Opinions disagree. In any case, once you have decided on the typographic policy, you can probably handle it using suitable contextual selectors (unless you need to worry about rather old versions of IE).

At one extreme, you could indent a paragraph only when it immediately follows another paragraph, since this is the context where indentation is really needed. As you normally want to prevent default vertical spacing between paragraphs when you use indentation, you would use

```
p + p { text-indent: 1em; }
p { margin: 0; }
```

(Using the `em` unit is superior to `px`, since it adapts to changes in font size. And normally `1em` is enough.)

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me while other solutions did not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nth-child pseudo class to achieve this. It accepts a formula as well substituting n with 0 and so on, so your formula becomes **2+n**

`p:nth-child(2+n){text-indent: 20px}`

```
<p>First</p>
<p>Second</p>
<p>Third</p>
```